# How can i divide string based on matematical symbole?

Tags: python, string, valueerror

At the start  sorry for my english. I wrote some code in PyCharm where i'am trying to divide string with mathematical operators such as +,-, itp and numbers but at the same time saving position of the mathematical operators and what they were.

```
string = '1234 - 4332 / 23 + 13 + 12 + 3213'
znaki = []
znakik = []
ilznak = string.count('+')+string.count('-')+string.count('/')+string.count('*')
i = [0,0,0,0]
num = string.split(" ")
print(num)
x = len(num)
while num.count('+')+i[0] >= i[0]:
    znaki.append('+')
    znakik.append(num.index('+'))
    print(znakik)
    num.pop(num.index('+'))
    i[0] = i[0] + 1
    print(num)
```

It's work sometimes but sometimes it gives me error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Prog/Python/Działaniastring.py", line 11, in <module>
    znakik.append(num.index('+')+i[0])
ValueError: '+' is not in list
```

Why is it that it pops sometimes but not always and what causes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. As a beginner in python you should definitely consider using python visualizer to understand the entire logic of the code. see [here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display)

Running your code gives this output:

```py
['1234', '-', '4332', '/', '23', '+', '13', '+', '12', '+', '3213']
[5]
['1234', '-', '4332', '/', '23', '13', '+', '12', '+', '3213']
[5, 6]
['1234', '-', '4332', '/', '23', '13', '12', '+', '3213']
[5, 6, 7]
['1234', '-', '4332', '/', '23', '13', '12', '3213']
```

And clearly when there remains no more '+' you would get the error that

> ValueError: '+' is not in list

So how does this happen?

```
1    znakik.append(num.index('+'))
2    num.pop(num.index('+'))
```

In line 2 you pop the '+' from the array on each iteration, i,e. the index value stored in the `znkakik` array. Once you do this for all you end up with no more '+', and then the error.

Comment: I understand what ValueError mean. But the same program when run second time give me correct output :

Comment: Interesting. I am confused as to how that can happen? From my understanding, you will always get the same output i've shown above. Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'second time'?

Comment: When i didnt change and jus run second time it gave mi correct output for some reason.